# mix-blend-mode difficulties (works on certain elements and not the other)

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

I'm currently learning CSS, and I'm experimenting with the **'mix-blend-mode'** property. I'm attempting to create a navbar that includes a logo (<h1> element) and a 'toggle-button', which should invert what's underneath it with 'difference' value. However, I'm encountering issues as it doesn't seem to work as expected. Interestingly, I have managed to make it work on other elements such as different images and even a custom cursor. I suspect that I might not be comprehending this property accurately, but I have been unable to locate any resources that provide a clearer explanation than what I currently understand ...

Here is my html :

```html
<body>
    <div class="cursor">
        <div class="cursor-small">

        </div>
        <div class="cursor-big"></div>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <div class="logo hoverable">
            <h1>LOGO</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-toggle hoverable">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

and my css :

```css
html {
  cursor: none;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: #530101;
}
```

cursor :

```css
.cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}
.cursor .cursor__small {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10001;
  /* background-color: blue; */
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
.cursor .cursor__big {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* background-color: red; */
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10001;
}
```

nav :

```css
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: var(--nav-height);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 10;
}
nav .logo h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
nav .menu-toggle {
  width: calc(40px + 1rem);
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav .menu-toggle div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  transition: all 75ms ease-in-out;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
nav .menu-toggle.toggled div:first-child {
  --translate-x: -0.5rem;
  transform: translate(var(--translate-x), var(--translate-y));
}
nav .menu-toggle.toggled div:last-child {
  --translate-x: 0.5rem;
  transform: translate(var(--translate-x), var(--translate-y));
}
nav .menu-toggle:hover div:first-child {
  --translate-y: -0.25rem;
  transform: translate(var(--translate-x), var(--translate-y));
}
nav .menu-toggle:hover div:last-child {
  --translate-y: 0.25rem;
  transform: translate(var(--translate-x), var(--translate-y));
}
```

I also tried backdrop-filter: invert(1) on my button divs but when I apply mix-blend-mode to the logo, the button disappear.
it's my first post here so I hope that it's clear (please excuse the awful css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to treat `mix-blend-mode` elements like layers.

In your case, you're trying to apply an operation like `difference` to your logo but the problem is your logo is on top of an element, in this case the `nav`, that has no background color and thus nothing to calculate.

I changed the color of the logo to blue just to make it obvious as white is barely noticeable in this case.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

```css
html {
  cursor: none;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: #530101;
}

.cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}
.cursor .cursor__small {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10001;
  /* background-color: blue; */
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
.cursor .cursor__big {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* background-color: red; */
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10001;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: var(--nav-height);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #530101;
}
nav .logo h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  color: blue;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.difference {
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

nav .menu-toggle {
  width: calc(40px + 1rem);
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav .menu-toggle div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  transition: all 75ms ease-in-out;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
nav .menu-toggle.toggled div:first-child {
  --translate-x: -0.5rem;
  transform: translate(var(--translate-x), var(--translate-y));
}
nav .menu-toggle.toggled div:last-child {
  --translate-x: 0.5rem;
  transform: translate(var(--translate-x), var(--translate-y));
}
nav .menu-toggle:hover div:first-child {
  --translate-y: -0.25rem;
  transform: translate(var(--translate-x), var(--translate-y));
}
nav .menu-toggle:hover div:last-child {
  --translate-y: 0.25rem;
  transform: translate(var(--translate-x), var(--translate-y));
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="cursor">
    <div class="cursor-small">

    </div>
    <div class="cursor-big"></div>
  </div>

  <nav>
    <div class="logo hoverable">
      <h1>LOGO</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-toggle hoverable">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </nav>


</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You made it clear in just a few lines :)